# sed nested group and backreferences

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Now I have one simple file I wanna sed on:

```
~ cat sample
##tag##
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
##tag##
```

What I expect is to remove the ##tag## line on pair and leave the middle stuff alone. I can do this (except there's one empty line at bottom):

```
~ sed -r 'N;N;N; s/##tag##\n((.*\n)*)##tag##/\1/' sample
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
```

But the tag line is not always as neat as I want, there's another file:

```
~ cat sample2
##tag###dklxjexx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
asdf##tag###xosy
```

I know you got my point, still I wanna remove the tag line:

```
~ sed -r 'N;N;N; s/##tag.*\n((.*\n)*).*tag##/\1/' sample2
```

But I got nothing print! How come??

I'm really looking forward for this q, Thanks for your time and forgive my poor English :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Foaik.png)

so is `.` matches `\n`? How's above img come?

Comment: `*` means 0 or more and `.*` is going to match the longest match meaning you capture group captures nothing and also the first `.*\n` matches to the last line.

Comment: thanks for your feedback! but I've found that `.*`  matches any character (except newline)

Comment: `.*` matches newlines as well...

Comment: yeah it seems like that `.` match `\n`, but can anyone explain the image? When that comes true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[^\n]*` instead of `.*`:

```
sed -r 'N;N;N; s/[^\n]*##tag[^\n]*\n(.*)\n[^\n]*tag##.*/\1/' sample2
```

Also, you need to take account of additional characters before/after the `'###tag##'` marker.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/##tag##/,//{//d}' file
```

To keep details on the tag lines as well, use:

```
sed '/##tag##/,//{s///}' file
```